# Missing support content for Chrome App and Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I noticed this morning that all support questions and feedback are missing from all my Chrome apps and extensions.

And not only from mine. I have looked at several other extensions I have installed in my browser and these are completely without any content on the support tab.

In the extension developer console there is no content either.

Reviews are still there.

What is this about?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I noticed this too. I didn't realize *all* support messages were gone, but it looks like they are! I have no idea why though.

Comment: Try [Reset Chrome settings to default](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/3296214?hl=en). Other than that, if you've developed your Chrome apps or extensions on Windows, Mac, and Linux, [read the announcement](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html) and learn more about [migrating your app](https://developers.chrome.com/apps/migration).

Comment: @Teyam: It's not about extensions not working, they do. But all support messages are gone for all extensions of all developers.

Comment: As of today, the support messages appear again

Comment: Yes, I have noticed it too.

Comment: Now the user counts are broken, apparently my extension has gone from 4,000+ users to 300,000+ :-) ... yay for me!